Mocking next-auth in storybook
I have a NextJS application with an app router that uses NextAuth.js that also includes Storybook.
Within the project, we have a HOC that wraps specific components with the authentication context (cutting out some of the Typescript markup to make it more succinct):
// context/AuthProvider.tsx
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
// ...
export default function AuthProvider({children}) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
}

// hoc/withAuthProvider.tsx
export const withAuthProvider = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const ComponentWithSP = (props) => {
    <AuthProvider>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    </AuthProvider>
  };
  return ComponentWithSP;
}

When the components are defined, they have:
export default withAuthProvider(MyClientComponent);

I want to write a Storybook story for MyClientComponent but cannot figure out how to mock the session or inject a mocked session.
My basic story looks like this:
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import MyClientComponent from './MyClientComponent';

const meta: Meta<typeof MyClientComponent> = {
  title: 'MyClientComponent',
  component: MyClientComponent,
};

export default meta;

export const MyClientComponentStory: StoryObj<typeof MyClientComponent> = {
  name: 'MyClientComponent',
};

Grabbing the session I didn't do anything special:
const { data: session, status } = useSession({
  required: true,
  onUnauthenticated() {
    redirect('/api/auth/signin');
  },
});

I found these:

https://dev.to/heymarkkop/how-to-use-nextauth-usesession-on-storybook-8-3eon - would work without the HOC but doesn't satisfy how this was set up by the original developers
https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/next-auth-mock - that is out-of-date and doesn't work (as are some others I found)
https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/mocking-modules#mock-files - I was trying to get this to work, but I still get my redirect
Mocking TypeScript imports for Storybook - This is what I am attempting to mess with now

Versions in use:

Node: 22.2.0
next: 14.2.3
next-auth: 4.24.7
storybook: 8.1.5


if my answer helped you, could you please give me an upvote? Did you try my suggesions?

Sorry, @Menelaos - I went on vacation for a couple weeks. I accept it now as it worked!

Try the following - just some ideas below...
Edit .storybook/preview.js to include a custom decorator that wraps your components with the SessionProvider (from NextAuth.js).
Then try to create a mock session object that reflects the state you want to simulate.
Use the mocked session in the SessionProvider.
Quick example (not working - but as an idea):
// .storybook/preview.js
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

const mockSession = {
  expires: '2023-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  user: {
    name: 'Storybook User',
    email: 'storybook@mySite.com',
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <SessionProvider session={mockSession}>
      <Story />
    </SessionProvider>
  ),
];

Now, when you define your Storybook stories:
// MyComponent.stories.js
import MyClientComponent from '../components/MyClientComponent';

export default {
  title: 'MyClientComponent',
  component: MyClientComponent,
};

export const Primary = () => <MyClientComponent />;

Give something like this a try and let me know if this helps you out!
